# How to validate a page using jQuery for passwords

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a div and it contains three input text boxes(oldpassword,newpassword,confirmpassword).

```
<div class="searchContainer" id="chngpassword">
        <div class="tableContent">
        <div class="leftContent">
            <div>Old Password<span class="redCLR">*</span></div>
            <div>New Password<span class="redCLR">*</span></div>
            <div>Confirm Password<span class="redCLR">*</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContent">
            <div><input type="password" name="OldPassword" id="OldPassword"  /></div>
            <div><input type="password" name="NewPassword" id="NewPassword" /></div>
            <div><input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="searchButton" style="margin:10px 0 0 0">
            <button id="btnSave">SAVE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now i have to validate the page in jquery for following scenarios:

1.Old password should not be blank.
2.New password should not be blank.
3.confirm password should not be blank.
4.old and confirm password should be same.
5.new password length should be 8-16 characters,atleast 1 special character,atleast 1 upper case,atleast 1 numericvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution that I think is what you are looking for . . .

```
function validatePassword(){
    var old_pass = $('#OldPassword').val();
    var new_pass = $('#NewPassword').val();
    var conf_pass = $('#ConfirmPassword').val();
    if(old_pass === ""){
        alert('Old password should not be blank.');
    }
    else if(new_pass === ""){
        alert('New password should not be blank.');
    }
    else if(conf_pass === ""){
        alert('Confirm password should not be blank');
    }
    else if(!new_pass.match(/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,16}$/))
        alert('New password length should be 8-16 characters,atleast 1 special character,atleast 1 upper case,atleast 1 numericvalue');
    }
    else if(new_pass !== conf_pass){
        alert('New and confirm password should be same');
    }
    return false    
}
```

This should do it. I have it on [JSFiddle if you want to see it working](http://jsfiddle.net/kLJQn/5/)